# Convert AJAX example from php to python/django

Tags: php, python, django, python-3.x

I'm reading an AJAX tutorial at www.w3schools.com. Their examples uses php and I only know django. I got most of the conversion done myself but would greatly appreciate someone helping with the rest.

Here is the php, I think I get down to the `foreach` block without having trouble:

```
 <?php
    // Array with names
    $a[] = "Anna";
    $a[] = "Brittany";
    $a[] = "Cinderella";
    $a[] = "Diana";
    $a[] = "Eva";
    $a[] = "Fiona";
    $a[] = "Gunda";
    $a[] = "Hege";
    $a[] = "Inga";
    $a[] = "Johanna";
    $a[] = "Kitty";
    $a[] = "Linda";
    $a[] = "Nina";
    $a[] = "Ophelia";
    $a[] = "Petunia";
    $a[] = "Amanda";
    $a[] = "Raquel";
    $a[] = "Cindy";
    $a[] = "Doris";
    $a[] = "Eve";
    $a[] = "Evita";
    $a[] = "Sunniva";
    $a[] = "Tove";
    $a[] = "Unni";
    $a[] = "Violet";
    $a[] = "Liza";
    $a[] = "Elizabeth";
    $a[] = "Ellen";
    $a[] = "Wenche";
    $a[] = "Vicky";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my python code so far:

```
def nameSuggestion(request):
    #list of names
    names = ["Ashley", "Rob", "Becky"]

    #get letters type from URL
    q = request.GET.get("q")

    #will hold name suggestion
    hint = ""

    #lookup all hints from 'names' if hint is not "":
    if q!="":
        q = q.lower()
        q_length = len(q)
        for character #I get confused at this part???
```

Comment: good edit didn't realize I formatted it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with a generator:

```
def nameSuggestion(request):
    a = [
        'Anna', 'Brittany', 'Cinderella', 'Diana', 'Eva', 'Fiona', 'Gunda', 'Hege',
        'Inga', 'Johanna', 'Kitty', 'Linda', 'Nina', 'Ophelia',
        'Petunia', 'Amanda', 'Raquel', 'Cindy', 'Doris', 'Eve',
        'Evita', 'Sunniva', 'Tove', 'Unni', 'Violet', 'Liza',
        'Elizabeth', 'Ellen', 'Wenche', 'Vicky'
    ]
    q = next(filter(None, (
        d.get('q') for d in [request.GET, request.POST, request.COOKIES]
    ), None)
    hint = ''
    if q:
        hint = ', '.join(name for name in a if name.startswith(q))
```

so we basically iterate over the `name`s in `a`, and check if `name` starts with the value we query for (`q`). If that is, we collect it, and we join these together with a comma.

You however will still need to find a way to construct a HTTP response (something you do not do in your PHP code either).

I think if you want to return JSON, you do not want to use these comma separated values, but return a list in JSON format:

```
def nameSuggestion(request):
    a = [
        'Anna', 'Brittany', 'Cinderella', 'Diana', 'Eva', 'Fiona', 'Gunda', 'Hege',
        'Inga', 'Johanna', 'Kitty', 'Linda', 'Nina', 'Ophelia',
        'Petunia', 'Amanda', 'Raquel', 'Cindy', 'Doris', 'Eve',
        'Evita', 'Sunniva', 'Tove', 'Unni', 'Violet', 'Liza',
        'Elizabeth', 'Ellen', 'Wenche', 'Vicky'
    ]
    q = next(filter(None, (
        d.get('q') for d in [request.GET, request.POST, request.COOKIES]
    ), None)
    hint = []
    if q:
        hint = [name for name in a if name.startswith(q)]
    return JsonResponse(hint)
```

Furthermore you can probably simplify the code by writing for example `q = request.GET.get('q')`. This is semantically not the same as `$_REQUEST['q']`, but it is seen frequently as bad design to "merge" GET, POST and COOKIES together.